# Converting all occurrence of True/False to 1/0 in a dataframe with mixed datatype

Tags: python, data-manipulation

**I have a dataframe** that has about 100 columns, There are some Boolean columns and some chars. I want to replace all Boolean having values True/False and also -1 with 1/0. I want to apply it on whole dataframe instead of single column.

I saw some solutions here, like converting the column to integer. But I want to avoid the exercise of going through 100s of columns.

Here is something I tried unsuccessfully:

```
test.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x=='True' else x)
test.applymap(lambda x: 0 if x=='False' else x)
```

But the dataframe test still has True/False

Comment: `x` may be equal to `True`, not `'True'`. Even so, you still need to convert the column type first; storing `1` in a boolean field will still just store `True`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`applymap` is not in-place by default, it will return a new dataframe.

The correct way:

```
test = test.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x == True else x)
test = test.applymap(lambda x: 0 if x == False else x)
```

or

```
test = test.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x == True else x).test.applymap(lambda x: 0 if x=='False' else x)
```

or simply

```
test.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x == True else x, inplace=True)
test.applymap(lambda x: 0 if x == False else x, inplace=True)
```

Although `replace` seems the best way of achieving this:

```
test.replace(False, 0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: possibly because, when I applied fillna, it converted the datatype from boolean to int64. Because all those columns currently have datatype int64.

Comment: Interestingly df.replace(False, 0) did not work for me.  I am running python 2.7 - although i doubt it is different in 3.0

Comment: @kiltannen much more likely to be related to pandas version.

Comment: Good to know - thanks.  The lambda replace did work well for me - but the df.replace just looked so much more elegant that I wanted to use it.

Answer (score 5):

For a single column, the simplest way by far is to convert the column type. Pandas is smart enough to map boolean to int correctly.

```py
df.column_name = df.column_name.astype(int)
```

If df.column_name starts as `Boolean`, it will become zeros and ones after converting to type `int`

Answer (score 1):

Define a function that loops the .replace() through each column of the Dataframe:

```
def replace_boolean(data):
    for col in data:
        data[col].replace(True, 1, inplace=True)
        data[col].replace(False, 0, inplace=True)

replace_boolean(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using multiplication by 1. If you do that, all your Data Frame will be transformed:

```
df*1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int(True)
```

or

```
int(1==1)
```

or to be used with lambda:

lambda x: int(x)

True will be 1, False will be 0 and -1 will be -1.